# Hilt with Android - Can I inject a dependency inside of a non-main thread Coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

Most of the discussion I see is how to inject the actual Coroutine contexts and workers. That's not what I'm talking about. Say I have a Service `myService()` and a library that needs to run in a Coroutine. I want to be able to inject a database into a child class that is instantiated within that Coroutine:

```
class myService : Service() {
    private val context = this

    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        scope.launch {
            Class1(context).doThing()
        }
        return startMode
}
```

`Class1`:

```
class Class1(context: myService){
    private val localContext = context
    private val class2impl = Class2()

    suspend fun doThing() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            withTimeoutOrNull(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(
                localContext.resources.getInteger(
                    R.integer.duration_seconds).toLong()
            )) {
                CoroutineLibrary{
                    ...
                    class2impl.finalThing(input)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

`Class2`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Class2 : AppCompatActivity (){

    @Inject
    lateinit var db: MyDatabase

    suspend fun finalThing(input: Input) {
        val myResult= db.myDao().doStuff(things)
    }
}
```

When I run this it tries to run instantiate `class2impl` and I get the error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()`

To me, that seems like Hilt injections can't be made on a thread that's not the main thread. To check this, I change only the line in the Service to:

`private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)`

Then the error message occurs when `finalThing` is actually called:

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized`

So lastly I kept the thread on `Main` and used constructor dependency injection:

`Class1`:

```
...
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface dbEntryPoint {
    fun db(): MyDatabase
}

val hiltEntryPoint =
    EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(localContext, dbEntryPoint::class.java)

val db = hiltEntryPoint.db()
private val class2impl = Class2(db)
...
```

In `Class2`, I comment out the original injection and just add to the constructor:

```
class Class2(private val db: MyDatabase) : AppCompatActivity (){
...
```

Functionally, it now works as expected. But it's running on the Main Thread. Is there a way to do this injection while on a background IO thread within this Service?

Comment: Are you trying to force Hilt to create an instance of an activity?

Comment: @TheLibrarian No, just the database which I have set up as a module like here:

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes

I can inject it fine in the ViewModel outside the context of the Service.

Comment: Why do you have Class2 as an activity?

Comment: Because @AndroidEntryPoint can only decorate certain classes, like in the beginning of the link here:

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes

If I made it a bare class, I wouldn't be able to inject anything within it.

Comment: Are you manually creating an instance of an Activity just to have Hilt give you some other dependency? Why not just have Hilt inject the constructor of Class2?

Comment: I have a lot of different logic that will be in Class1 and Class2, and only Class2 really needs the database, so I thought separation of concerns would lead to this type of architecture.

I have tried injecting the constructor, but I still get the error about Looper, since it's running on the IO thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255069/discussion-between-thelibrarian-and-mw2023).